# Model not returning values to controller from dynamically added content?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I have schedule times that can be added dynamically from code behind using Ajax. The user can click an add button and jquery Ajax call should add another set of fields to add a schedule time. From some reason, my model is not returning any values to the controller when I click save.

I've tried using a different model that also includes Date, Start Time and End Time, but the returns no values as well. It seems like the values from the fields are not being posted from the form.

The HTML form

```
<form asp-action="SetSchedule" asp-controller="Admin" method="post" id="addEventForm">
                <table id="scheduleTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Start Time</th>
                            <th>End Time</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>

                <br />
                <button id="addScheduleButton" type="button">Add Schedule Time</button>
                <button id="savePendingButton" type="submit" style="margin-left:1em" hidden>Save</button>
            </form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public IActionResult SetSchedule(ScheduleViewModel model)
        {
            _adminManager.SetInterviewSchedule(model);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(ViewSchedule));
        }
```

Model:

```
public class ScheduleViewModel
    {
        public List<Schedule> ScheduleItems { get; set; } = new List<Schedule>();

        //public InterviewInfoApplicationViewModel InterviewInfo { get; set; } = new InterviewInfoApplicationViewModel();
    }

    public class Schedule
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateAvailable { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

        public bool IsSelected { get; internal set; }
    }
```

Fields to append on ajax call page:

```
@model Ambassadors.Managers.ViewModels.Admin.Schedule

@{
    string rowClass = "pendingScheduleRow";
}

    <tr class="@rowClass" style="margin-top:1em">
        <td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DateAvailable)
            <input type="text" asp-for="DateAvailable" class="datepickerInput" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StartTime)
            <input type="text" asp-for="StartTime" class="timepickerInput" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EndTime)
            <input type="text" asp-for="EndTime" class="timepickerInput" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="tooltip deletePendingSchedule" title="Remove Schedule Time" style="cursor:pointer">
                <span class="wdn-icon-cancel" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="wdn-text-hidden">cancel icon</span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Script:

```
    require(['jquery', 'jqueryui'], function ($, jqueryui) {

        $(function () {
  $('body').on('focus', ".datepickerInput", function () {
                    $(this).datepicker({
                        controlType: "select",

                    });
                });

                $('body').on('focus', ".timepickerInput", function () {
                    $(this).timepicker({
                        timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
                        interval: 5,
                        dropdown: true,
                        scrollbar: true
                    });
                });

                $("#addScheduleButton").click(function () {
                    var nextIndex = $(".pendingScheduleRow").length;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Admin/AddScheduleItem",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            index: nextIndex
                        },
                        success: function (results) {
                            $("table#scheduleTable tbody").append(results);
                            $("#savePendingButton").show();
                        }
                    });
                });

                $("#scheduleTable").on("click", ".deletePendingSchedule", function () {

                    var closestRow = $(this).closest("tr");

                    $(closestRow).hide();

                    var visibleRows = $(".pendingScheduleRow:visible").length;

                    if (visibleRows === 0) {

                        $("#savePendingButton").hide();
                    }

                });

        });

    });
```

Model should return DateAvailable, StartTime and EndTimes to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your action receives model type of `ScheduleViewModel` who has a property of `List<Schedule>` while your view `asp-for="DateAvailable"` neither bind to `ScheduleViewModel` nor bind to `List<Schedule>`.

Refer to my below demo:

1.AddScheduleItem action to return `index` to partial view

```
public IActionResult AddScheduleItem(string index)
    {
        var myViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary()) 
                         { 
                            { "index", index }
                         };
        PartialViewResult result = new PartialViewResult()
        {
            ViewName = "YourPartialViewName",
            ViewData = myViewData,
        };

        return result;

    }
```

2.YourPartailView:

```
@model ScheduleViewModel

@{
    string rowClass = "pendingScheduleRow";
    int index = Int32.Parse(@ViewData["index"].ToString());
}

<tr class="@rowClass" style="margin-top:1em">
    <td>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ScheduleItems[index].DateAvailable)
        <input asp-for="ScheduleItems[index].DateAvailable" class="datepickerInput" />
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ScheduleItems[index].StartTime)
        <input asp-for="ScheduleItems[index].StartTime" class="timepickerInput" />
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ScheduleItems[index].EndTime)
        <input asp-for="ScheduleItems[index].EndTime" class="timepickerInput" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="tooltip deletePendingSchedule" title="Remove Schedule Time" style="cursor:pointer">
            <span class="wdn-icon-cancel" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="wdn-text-hidden">cancel icon</span>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
```